# Using a system of equations to graph the temperature change of a boiler

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy

An exercise lists several equations and constants for a boiler system. These are to be used to plot a graph showing the change of temperature over time until the boiling point is reached.

The exercise states to numerically solve the following equation:

$$
Q_{net}=Q_{in}-Q_{out}=(m_{boiler}×c_{boiler}+m_{water}×c_{water})×\frac {ΔT_{(boiler\;and\;water\;system)}}{Δtime}
$$
$$
where\;\; T_{(boiler\;and\;water\;system)} ≤212℉
$$

To simplify the problem, the exercise says to treat the boiler pot and the water as if they are always the same temperature.

For heat loss, the exercise states to use the following equation:

$$
\frac {Q_{loss}}{dt} = \frac {Q_{convect}}{dt} + \frac {Q_{rad}}{dt} = hA(T_{boiler}-T_{room})+K_{coef}((T_{boiler}+460)^4-(T_{room}+460)^4)
$$

The following are given as constants:

$$
heat\; rate = 1200 \frac {Btu}{hr} \;,\; 
m_{boiler}=0.288 lb_m \;,\;
c_{boiler}=0.12 \frac {Btu}{lb_m×℉} \;,\;
water\; volume = 6\; oz\;,\; 
$$
$$
hA = 0.5 \frac {Btu}{hr×℉}\;,\;
K_{coef} = 5×10^{-9}\frac {Btu}{hr×°R^4}\;,\;
T_{ambiemt} = 70℉
$$

Solving for this should produce the following graph as the answer:

[image: Temperature v Time graph]

The exercise suggests using a spreadsheet to solve for this, so I created three columns to iterate through solving the unknowns. I made the first column a time column with increments of 0.5 seconds, the second a heat-loss column where the constants are plugged in and the first row has the boiler temperature set to 70℉ so that the net heat is zero, and the last column arranged to account for the change in temperature so that

$$
T = 70℉+ \frac {Q_{in}-Q_{out}}{(m_{boiler}×c_{boiler}+m_{water}×c_{water})}×{Δtime}
$$
$$
= 70℉+ \frac {(1200 \frac{Btu}{hr}-Q_{out})(\frac{hr}{3600 \;sec})}{(0.288 lb_m)(0.12 \frac{Btu}{lb_m℉})+(0.00626628 ft^3)(62.4 \frac {lb_m}{ft^3})(0.12 \frac{Btu}{lb_m℉}))}×{Δtime}
$$

So, for cell A3 I entered the formula as

> =0.5*(C3-70)+(5*10^(-9))*((C3+459.67)^4-(70+459.67)

and for cell C3 I entered the formula as

> =70+((1200-A2)*(1/3600))/((0.288)*(0.12)+(0.00626628)*(62.4)*(1))*B3

While my approach seems to be on the right track, the boiling point should be reached by ~325 seconds according to the solution, but the approach I used never gets there.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Without going through all your calculations, the temperature in last graph, as I see it , is still rising, albeit very slowly, after 100 seconds.

Comment: I suspect I'm on the right track since it is raising, but it should raise more quickly.  It should reach the 212℉ boiling point at the same pace as in the first graph, but it levels out instead.

Comment: Wait a minute.  The two graphs don't differ that much.  Maybe they used 6 oz by mass rather than 6 oz by volume.

Comment: Ha, I'm not as well versed in the English system and hadn't considered that ounce could refer to either mass or volume. Your comment is helpful, Chet... it's a good reminder to be cautious about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordinary differential equation you should be solving numerically is $$\frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{(Q_{in}-Q_{out})}{(m_{water}c_{water}+m_{boiler}c_{boiler})}$$where $Q_{out}$ is evaluated at the instantaneous temperature T .  The initial condition for the integration is T = 70 F at t = 0.  Do you know the Euler forward finite difference integration formula for this integration?  The Euler finite difference approximation to the equation $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(y)$ is $$y(t+\Delta t)=y(t)+f(y(t))\Delta t$$

I reduced the equation, using T as the Rankine temperature and t in seconds, to:
$$\frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{(1859.5-0.5T-5\times 10^{-9}T^4)}{1532.}$$
Using a time step of 1 sec, I reached 212 F (672 R) at 259 seconds.

Comment: I updated the post to give more clarity to my Excel approach, which (I think) was in line with your previous response. I see you have since edited your message and I will respond as soon as I have the chance to play around with the equation you wrote.

Comment: Shouldn't the approach I took effectively accomplish the same thing since I am using small time intervals as a substitute for infinitesimals, which approximate the curve?

Comment: No.  You don't start from 70 at each step.  You use the temperature from the previous step.

Comment: Also, I would be solving this in terms of the Rankine temperature T+460, rather than in terms of T.  That would reduce the amount of arithmetic.  Would you like me to run the calculation for comparison?

Comment: See my addition.  I integrated numerically on an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmm... I'd previously had my Excel formulas set to taking the temperature from the previous step, but started doubting myself when the temperature differed from the given solution. I also got ~259 seconds by doing so. Using T = 70 for each step gave a graph similar to the solution, so I figured I was on the right track if I did that instead. It's reassuring that you got the same as my initial result, though I wonder why this differs significantly from the solution?

Comment: Who knows what they did.  All we can be confident about is what we did.

Comment: That's a good bit of wisdom to live by.